# Permission Denied CIFS. Tried everything I can think of

Tags: fstab, cifs, smb

```
//192.168.1.64/d /media/d cifs credentials=/home/nick/.smbcredentials,uid=nick,gid=media,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nofail,user 0 0
```

Here's my ls- l of the share once mounted:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 nick media 0 Jan 20  2023  Blurays2
drwxrwxrwx 2 nick media 0 Jul 26 18:37  cache
drwxrwxrwx 2 nick media 0 Feb  5  2021 'Childrens Movies2'
drwxrwxrwx 2 nick media 0 Jan 22  2023  Movies2
drwxrwxrwx 2 nick media 0 Aug  5 22:34  temp-movies
drwxrwxrwx 2 nick media 0 Jul 11 14:08  tv_shows
```

and here's my share info from the server via the smb.conf file

```
[d]
path = /media/nick/Backup Drive/
valid users = share, nick
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
force create mode = 0666
force directory mode = 0777
```

Can anyone see what the heck I am missing?

Comment: Has it ever worked? Have you created a Samba user account on the server (`smbpasswd -a nick` as root)? What are the permissions on the directory `/media/nick/Backup Drive` (ideally `0777` if no-one else uses the server directly)? Have you tried double-quoting the path in the `smb.conf` file? What are the related error messages in the recently-modified files under `/var/log/samba` on the server (you might need to use `log level 3` to see them)?

Comment: Um. The share mounted. So what is triggering the "_permission denied_" that you've mentioned in the question title?

Comment: The 0777 did it! I did the chmod on the /media/d on the client machine once I mounted it but I didn't realize I needed to do it on the host machine as well.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that `/media/nick/Backup Drive` is accessible by your target users `share` and `nick`.

Provided noone else is using the server directly you can choose to relax the filesystem permissions entirely and leave Samba to manage access control:

```
chmod a=rwx '/media/nick/Backup Drive'
```